# VBA Excel: Local variables stored in memory?

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA Excel,

I've heard that it's good to declare variables, that are of no further use, as `Nothing` in the end of module to save memory.

Example:

```
Dim myRange As Range

Sub Main

   set myRange = Sheets("Sheet1").range("A1:H20")
   ' Do Something
   ' ...
   set myRange = Nothing

End Sub
```

Is there any truth to this statement or does VBA Excel handle this issue automatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a need to set Objects to Nothing inside VBA Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517006/is-there-a-need-to-set-objects-to-nothing-inside-vba-functions)

Comment: Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106153/vba-garbage-collector-details

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11396211/78522

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables declared within the scope of your procedure are destroyed correctly afterwards.

So in your example, because `myRange` is defined within the scope of `Main` it is destroyed/cleaned up appropriately.

However, if you had a module with this code:

```
Public testForStackOverflow As Range

Sub main()
    Call mySubSub
    MsgBox testForStackOverflow.Address

    Call mySubDestroyer
    If (testForStackOverflow Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox "destroyed"
    End If

    Call mySubSub
End Sub

Sub mySubSub()
    Set testForStackOverflow = Range("A1")
End Sub
Sub mySubDestroyer()
    Set testForStackOverflow = Nothing
End Sub

Sub callAfterRunningMain()

    MsgBox testForStackOverflow.Address
End Sub
```

the global is not automatically cleaned up after `mySubSub` (as should be expected).

What you might *not* expect is that if you run `callAfterRunningMain` after running the `main` method, your global still has a value. This global is not cleaned up unless you manually do it, close Excel, or use `End` somewhere in your code.

So if you heavily used global variables and did not clean them up somehow, you will keep them in memory indefinitely. This is the case with userforms and using `UserForm.hide` vs `Unload Me` too, by the way.

---

The related questions don't really address what I describe and it can be quite confusing. Especially when trying to "reset" UserForms.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you do not do that, the fact that the variable goes out of scope will have the any un-referenced object garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with a large number of object variables, like a `Range', at one time, or in a loop that re-creates them before disposing of old objects, Excel will have a problem with that.
Garbage collection occurs when Excel thinks it should; some indeterminate time after a variable goes out of scope.

If you are doing lots of repetitions of object variable creation, without leaving the scope in which they are created, it is a **very** good idea to dispose of them (`..=Nothing`) when you are done with them.