# Excel VBA write to file for multi dimensional data

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I have three dimensional data that I want to write into file in VBA. The data will have a time axis, a spatial axis, and a magnitude axis. So, the magnitude data would be in the form of A(space, time). Does anyone know how to "write" that into a text file in vba code? I'm not sure how to loop around "Write #1" with two indices.  Thanks for helping out!

Here's the output I'm expecting:

```
         space1  space2  space3
time1    A(1,1)  A(1,2)  A(1,3)
time2    A(2,1)  A(2,2)  A(2,3)
time3    A(3,1)  A(3,2)  A(3,3)
```

Comment: What code do you have at the moment?

Comment: Why not write it out as a list of time, space, value?

Comment: Is that how the data also appears within excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `Scripting Runtime` library. You could do a simple tab delimited file. If you want you could reference the `Scripting` library directly in the VBE editor:
Tools->Reference->Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Here's some untested code you could go off of:

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim oFile As TextStream
Dim iTime As Integer, iSpace As Integer

Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(stringPath)

For iTime = 1 To UBound(A)
    For iSpace = 1 To UBound(A, 2)
        oFile.WriteLine (iTime & vbTab & iSpace & vbTab & A(iTime, iSpace))
    Next iSpace
Next iTime

oFile.Close
Set oFile = Nothing
```

For late bound reference to library see:
[How to create and write to a txt file using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503174/how-to-create-and-write-to-a-txt-file-using-vba)