# Avoid loop while working with excel to notepad

Tags: excel, notepad, vba

I use the below code to copy some range from excel to notepad.But its very slow when i work more than 1 lakh (100,000) data . Is there any shorter way to achieve this without using send keys method.

```
Sub PrintToTextFile()

Dim FileNum As Integer, cl As Range, z As Integer, y As Integer

Dim myStr As String

FileNum = FreeFile ' next free filenumber

'Open "C:\Temp\TEXTFILE.TXT" For Output As #FileNum ' creates the new file

Open "C:\temp\TEXTFILE.TXT" For Append As #FileNum

Print #FileNum, [a1]

z = 10

For Each cl In [b1:b123400]

    y = cl.Row

    If y = z Then

        myStr = myStr & "|" & cl

        'appends the input to an existing file write to the textfile

    Else: Print #FileNum, myStr

        z = cl.Row

        myStr = "": myStr = myStr & "|" & cl

    End If

Next

'appends the input to an existing file write to the textfile

Print #FileNum, myStr

Close #FileNum ' close the file

End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create and write to a txt file using VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503174/how-to-create-and-write-to-a-txt-file-using-vba)

Comment: Try the suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503174/how-to-create-and-write-to-a-txt-file-using-vba) using FSO and WriteLine methods (still in a loop, but I think should be faster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRIED AND TESTED with (1.5 Lakhs i.e 150,000 rows) - Time Taken 1 Second**

This should be faster as it doesn't loop through the cells and write to the file at the same time. It makes use of the array.

```
Sub PrintToTextFile()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FileNum As Integer, z As Long, y As Long, i As Long
    Dim myStr As String
    Dim Myar, ArOutput() As String

    '~~> Set this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Myar = ws.Range("b1:b123400").Value

    FileNum = FreeFile ' next free filenumber

    Open "C:\temp\TEXTFILE.TXT" For Append As #FileNum

    Print #FileNum, ws.Range("A1").Value

    z = 10

    For i = LBound(Myar) To UBound(Myar)
        If i = z Then
            myStr = myStr & "|" & Myar(i, 1)
        Else
            ReDim Preserve ArOutput(y)
            ArOutput(y) = myStr
            y = y + 1
            z = i
            myStr = "": myStr = myStr & "|" & Myar(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    For i = LBound(ArOutput) To UBound(ArOutput)
        Print #FileNum, ArOutput(i)
    Next i

    'appends the input to an existing file write to the textfile
    Print #FileNum, myStr
    Close #FileNum ' close the file
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Code used for  above testing.

```
Sub PrintToTextFile()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FileNum As Integer, z As Long, y As Long, i As Long
    Dim myStr As String
    Dim Myar, ArOutput() As String

    Debug.Print "Process Started at " & Now

    '~~> Set this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Myar = ws.Range("B1:B150000").Value

    FileNum = FreeFile ' next free filenumber

    Open "C:\temp1\TEXTFILE.TXT" For Output As #FileNum

    Print #FileNum, ws.Range("A1").Value

    z = 10

    For i = LBound(Myar) To UBound(Myar)
        If i = z Then
            myStr = myStr & "|" & Myar(i, 1)
        Else
            ReDim Preserve ArOutput(y)
            ArOutput(y) = myStr
            y = y + 1
            z = i
            myStr = "": myStr = myStr & "|" & Myar(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    For i = LBound(ArOutput) To UBound(ArOutput)
        Print #FileNum, ArOutput(i)
    Next i

    'appends the input to an existing file write to the textfile
    Print #FileNum, myStr
    Close #FileNum ' close the file

    Debug.Print "Process ended at " & Now
End Sub
```