# How to convert an excel cell into a HTML file?

Tags: html, vba, google-maps, excel

I would like to ask for some help (again), here's my context : I'm trying to create an Excel Worksheet that I can add some coordinates and generate an html page with a map using Google Maps API and his markers.

I have successfully created a macro that get the data from my SQL Server and that also create the html structure (tags,header,body,etc.).

Here's my problem : There is a way to create a macro that get the value of my cell (that contains the HTML structure) and transform it into a HTML page? (Also, I have to be able to save this file into a directory, because it will be used by other users)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could do this with a separate program that reads the Excel file's contents as a string, and writes that string to a file.  That's fairly trivial in C# or VB.

Comment: Hi Jim. Yeah, I agree, but the problem is that has to be an Excel, because other programs are not allowed in the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question basically boils down to this... How do I read the value from a cell and save it to a text file?  After all, an HTML file is just a text file with the .html file extension.

So, I assume you already know how to read the value of a cell.  Now comes the question of how to write that string to a text file, and that part of the question has been answered before, both in MSDN articles that you can find via a Google search, and right here on SO...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11503299/1246574

Hope this helps.  Sometimes solving a seemingly complex problem is about breaking the question into simplified parts.

Comment: Jim, thank you very much for you help. In fact, now it's really clear, as you said, it was just how to create a text file and change the extension!