# Outlook macro that checks if Excel macro is running

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have an Excel macro that opens Internet Explorer, searches & requests an export for each item in Column A.

The export is sent to my Outlook email and automatically filters into my Import/Export folder. At that point, when it filters into my Import/Export folder, I'd like **an Outlook macro to check if the Excel macro is running**, because I receive exports at other times too.

**If the Excel macro is running I'd like to change/edit the subject line of the email that was just filtered to include the text from a certain HTML tag (which I have the ID for) on the current page from Internet Explorer.**

** Is this possible? If you have any suggestion on a better way to go about this I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: I think the result would be the same if you sent mail with the required Subject.

Comment: I don't think you understand the goal I'm trying to accomplish. The subject needs to be changed automatically. I'm not sending the email when I request the export. The system sends me an email with the same Subject that is used for every export.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, just before the first export save 1 to a text file. Once all exports are done, put Excel to sleep for a short time so the mail can reach Outlook then save 0 to the text file.

In Outlook, assume Excel is requesting exports if the text file contains 1.

Edit:
Sample code for Excel [How to create and write to a txt file using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503174/how-to-create-and-write-to-a-txt-file-using-vba)
Sample code for Outlook: [Read/Parse text file line by line in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba)

Comment: Though it's not a bad workaround, I'm looking to do this with just the use of the excel and outlook macros

Comment: Its the best approach you will get.