# what control should I use to print a long message to a windows in access VBA 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am writting a test code in access 2007 (VBA) that would test the data and report if any record has problem.
It would do it by checking data with external data, so I am not using any of the access reporting tools.

This is an internal tools and will be used only by me, so the UI is not that important.

What I am doing is to write a VBA code that read recordset and external data and check the recordset.

I can do this, but I need a way to print this on UI. Something such as this:

> Record no 10 is not valid : reason XXXX
>
> Record 15 is not valid: reason YYYY

I was thinking of using a multi line text box to output this on screen, but I have several problem:

1. I can not find any way to make a text box as a multi line text box. There is no multi line propertyso I can output a line break.
2. If the size of recordset is big and there are a lot of errors, I am getting error that the size pro text proprty is too big.

What *control* should I use? I was thinking about using a *label control*, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: What's wrong with a TextBox on a form?

Answer (score 0):

The `UserForm` control in VBA has a `MultiLine` property, which you can set to `True`.

The other property is the `EnterKeyBehavior` that needs to be set to `True` to allow line breaks.

Alternately yes, you could use a `Label` control to achieve the same and even format it to look like a TextBox if you care.

But if long string of data, I would consider outputing it straight to a file with `Open` and `For Output` or `For Append`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `Debug.Print` (output goes to the Immediate window -> Ctrl+g).

An Access text box that is large enough is always multi-line capable, there is no special property for that. Just append `vbCrLf` to each line to create a line break.

```
Me.txtLog = Me.txtLog & strError & vbCrLf
```

But for really long text output, a **log file** is the best option.

To write text files: either use [FileSystemObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503174/how-to-create-and-write-to-a-txt-file-using-vba) or the old fashioned [Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264163.aspx) statement.