# Excel VBA: check if .txt file is open / locked / free

Tags: vba, excel, updates

I have written a small application using Excel vba to update a .txt file, whereby when the user submits an submission, a counter would update the .txt file so that we would know the current running number, and also keeping track of the daily submission.

The .txt file only stores the current number. (i.e. +1 to the current number for every submission).

However, i notice that it causes error when 2 users submitting a submission at the same time. May I know how can i do a check to see if the .txt file is opened, and lock it for just the user only? Or to only allow one update at a time, the rest would be blocked.

Please advise, thank you so much!

Below is the code written to update the .txt file

```
Sub TextFile_FindReplace(ByRef FileCount As Long)

Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim fileDate As String, todDate As String
Dim text As String, textline As String

FilePath = "c:\fileNoCount.txt"
todDate = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
TextFile = FreeFile

Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
Line Input #TextFile, fileDate
Close #TextFile

If DateValue(fileDate) <> todDate Then
    Open FilePath For Output As TextFile
    Print #TextFile, todDate
    Print #TextFile, "1"
    Close TextFile
Else
    Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #TextFile, textline
            text = text & textline
        Loop
    Close TextFile

    FileCount = textline + 1
    Open FilePath For Output As TextFile
    Print #TextFile, todDate
    Print #TextFile, FileCount
    Close TextFile
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check If a File Is Already Open (vba)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599322/check-if-a-file-is-already-open-vba)

Comment: Trap the error you get if the file is already locked by another user, insert a short delay then try again.  You can put that in a loop for a reasonable number of tries before giving up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create and write to a txt file using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503174/how-to-create-and-write-to-a-txt-file-using-vba)