# Excel VBA Export data as CSV

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv, vba

I have an Excel file with multiple sheets. I need a macro that does the following.

1. Select a sheet with the specified sheet name.
2. Select all rows from the sheet where length of 1st column data is greater than one
3. Export the selected data as a CSV file in a specified directory.

I have a very basic understanding of Excel VBA and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide you with some sample code. Since we are not here for writing whole code, it will be your task to go deeper and put the code together.

**1.** If you want to select sheet, you need to call `Select` method of sheet object. There are multiple ways of referencing sheets, but most common (IMO) is `Sheets("Name of the sheet").Select`.

**2a.** For selecting cells, the procedure is the same, but instead of sheets, you have to use cell object, i.e.: `Cells(r, c).Select` (again, this isn't the only ways of referencing cells, another one: `Range("A1").Select`), where `r` and `c` are integers representing row and column respectively. Generally, you need to call `Select` on object of `Range` type.

**SUMMARY**

So far, I covered how to select certain object in the workbook, but it's not optimal way of doing it. Unless you need to select thing explicitly, I wouldn't do it. Instead you can get value of certain cell in certain sheet using following syntax:

```
Sheets("SheetName").Cells(r, c).Value
```

This is combined previous parts of code, which accesses value of a cell in row `r` and column `c` in sheet named `SheetName`, without selecting anything. This way you can either set or get the value.

**2b.** If you want to test something, like condition, use `If` statement. In your case it would look like:

```
If Len( Sheets("SheetName").Cells(r, c).Value ) > 1 Then
    'do something if it's true
Else
    'do something if it's false
End If
```

**3.** You would have to create some string variable, something like `Dim content As String` where you'd append all data from cells that passed your test. At the end, after all, you could write this text variable to a file. This might be useful: [How to create and write to a txt file using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503174/how-to-create-and-write-to-a-txt-file-using-vba)

Additionally, you need to loop through all rows, so you need loop statements, go here for more details: [Loops in VBA](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Loops.html)

I hope that will give you some clue about what to do and how to do :)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you pretty close to where you want to be.

```
Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xDir As String
Dim folder As FileDialog
Set folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If folder.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xDir = folder.SelectedItems(1)
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
xWs.SaveAs xDir & "\" & xWs.Name, xlCSV
Next
End Sub
```