# Write and replace string into txt file down an excel list

Tags: vba, excel, text

I would be incredibly appreciative if someone could point me to the right approach to accomplish this.

I have an excel table that is list of batters for a little league softball team. I would like to write each name into a txt file, one at a time as they come to bat, and replace the previous one. The contents of the txt file will be overlayed onto a video stream. So each time a girl comes up, I would like to do something easy that will allow the next line in the excel table to be written into the text file replacing the previous text.

Thanks!

Comment: For reading and writing text files have a seach for FileSystemObject VBA. Or see this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503174/how-to-create-and-write-to-a-txt-file-using-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This set up automatically changes to next batter, and resets at the start of the lineup. Click button every new batter.

[image]

```
Sub saveAsTxt()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim wsTwo As Worksheet
        Set wsTwo = Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim NextBatterCounter As String
        NextBatterCounter = ws.Range("C4")

    Dim filePath As String
        filePath = "Z:\New folder\"

    Dim fileName As String
        fileName = "BatterUp"

    ' Go to Tools -> References... and check "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" to be able to use
    ' the FileSystemObject which has many useful features for handling files and folders

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fileStream As TextStream

    Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath & fileName)

    fileStream.WriteLine ws.Range("A" & NextBatterCounter)

    fileStream.Close

    If ws.Range("C4") < 16 Then
        ws.Range("C4") = ws.Range("C4") + 1
    Else
        ws.Range("C4") = 2
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is way over my head, but I was able to fumble through it to make it work and even add another macro and list so I have separate Home and Away orders. Can't tell you how much I appreciate this! No thanks to Mod who put this "on hold" for not enough info as the above answer was exactly what I needed!

Comment: glad that it worked and that you were able to learn from it and hope that it makes the softball game even more fun! i think that it was put on hold because mods like to see some code! i am glad it worked out, keep posting, take care

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, which will output the value of the (first) selected cell which overlaps a predetermined range to a specified text file.

This is triggered by a selection change, so a new file will be output whenever a new (matching) cell is selected - so the code should go in the appropriate worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    Dim rFind As Range
    Dim sTxt As String
    Dim sPath As String

    'Change path / name for text file output
    sPath = "C:\Temp\XLText.txt"

    'Change to range continaing the list of values to select / output
    Set rFind = Sheet1.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Column1").DataBodyRange

    Set r = Intersect(Target, rFind)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        sTxt = r.Cells(1).Value
       WriteTextFile sTxt, sPath
    End If

End Sub


Sub WriteTextFile(ByVal s As String, ByVal sPath As String)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim oFi As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFi = fso.CreateTextFile(sPath)

    oFi.WriteLine s
    oFi.Close

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFi = Nothing
End Sub
```