# Exporting Excel rows to text files

Tags: excel, vba

There are a few solutions I've seen but they don't specifically do what i'm trying to.

What I need to be able to do:

- each row to create a new text file
- each cell is a new line in this text file
- the file name is the value in column 2
- the file extension ".nfo"
- the folder to be saved into is the value (an absolute path) in column 1
- loop from row 3 to the first null row

I would post code but I have no idea where to start. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Seems like a pretty straightforward FOR loop for the reading task, and FSO for the writing task. You can read the documentation for that here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement and FSO: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/filesystemobject-object

Comment: This is one way to handle [How to create and write to a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503174/how-to-create-and-write-to-a-txt-file-using-vba)

Answer (score 0):

As an example, I used the answer from the link I posted in comments.
I put a simple loop inside that loops the range, creating a row in the text file for each value.

Then I call with from another sub (not something you have to do) from within a loop that loop through all the rows, and for each row, passes the range of all the used column in said row. This specific code requires you to add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveNfo()
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, LastColumn As Range, rngRow As Variant
Set ws = Worksheets(1)
Set rng = ws.Range("A3:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) 'start on row 3, include all rows with a filepath

For Each rngRow In rng
    If Not rngRow = "" Then
        SaveTextToFile rngRow & rngRow.Offset(, 1), _
        ws.Range(rngRow.Offset(, 2), Cells(rngRow.Row, ws.Cells(rngRow.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
    End If
Next
End Sub

Private Sub SaveTextToFile(filePath As String, rng As Range)
    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim fileStream As TextStream
    ' Here the actual file is created and opened for write access
    Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath)
    ' Write something to the file
    For Each cell In rng
            fileStream.WriteLine cell
    Next
    ' Close it, so it is not locked anymore
    fileStream.Close
End Sub
```

If the file name column doesn't include *.nfo* you can add that in the code manually:

`SaveTextToFile rngRow & rngRow.Offset(, 1), _`  Becomes
`SaveTextToFile rngRow & rngRow.Offset(, 1) & ".nfo", _`

`rngRow` points to the "A" column, for the path.
`rngRow.Offset(, 1)` is then the "B" column, for the name.
`rngRow.Offset(, 2)` is then ofc "C", where we start looking for data to put in the file.

Or, if you want the really short version:

```
Sub SaveNfo()
Dim rngRow As Variant, cell As Variant, fso As Object, fileStream As Object
For Each rngRow In Range("A3:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Not rngRow = "" Then
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(rngRow & rngRow.Offset(, 1))
        For Each cell In Range(rngRow.Offset(, 2), Cells(rngRow.Row, Cells(rngRow.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
            fileStream.WriteLine cell
        Next
        fileStream.Close
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Export Rows to Text Files

- Copy the complete code into a standard module.
- Before running `exportRowsToTextFiles`, adjust the values in its constants section and the worksheet (e.g. `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`).
- Uncomment the various `Debug.Print` lines to better understand how it works by monitoring the output in the `Immediate window`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub exportRowsToTextFiles()
    
    Const First As String = "A3" ' First Data Cell Address
    Const fCol As Long = 1 ' First Column
    Const fpCol As Long = 1 ' File Path Column
    Const fbnCol As Long = 2 ' File Base Name Column
    Const fExt As String = ".nfo" ' File Extension
    Const ccSep As String = vbLf ' Cell Contents Separator
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' if run from an Add-in
    If TypeName(ActiveSheet) <> "Worksheet" Then Exit Sub ' if e.g. chart
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim brrg As Range: Set brrg = refBottomRightRange(ws.Range(First))
    'Debug.Print "Bottom Right Range: " & brrg.Address
    
    Dim nerg As Range: Set nerg = refNonEmptyRange(brrg)
    If nerg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    'Debug.Print "Non-Empty Range:    " & nerg.Address
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = getRange(nerg)
    'Debug.Print "Data Array:", "Rows=" & UBound(Data, 1), _
        "Columns=" & UBound(Data, 2)

    Dim rDat As Variant: ReDim rDat(0 To UBound(Data, 2) - fCol)
    
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Len(Data(r, fpCol)) > 0 Then
            If Len(Data(r, fbnCol)) > 0 Then
                FilePath = Data(r, fpCol) & pSep & Data(r, fbnCol) & fExt
                'Debug.Print FilePath
                n = -1
                For c = fCol To UBound(Data, 2)
                    n = n + 1
                    rDat(n) = Data(r, c)
                    'Debug.Print r, c, n, rDat(n)
                Next c
            End If
        End If
        writeStringToFile FilePath, Join(rDat, ccSep)
    Next r
    
End Sub

Function refBottomRightRange( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    With FirstCell.Worksheet
        Set refBottomRightRange _
            = .Range(FirstCell(1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count))
    End With
End Function
Sub refBottomRightRangeTEST()
    Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = Range("C5")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = refBottomRightRange(FirstCell)
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then Debug.Print rg.Address
End Sub

Function refBottomRightResize( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    With FirstCell
        Set refBottomRightResize = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, _
            .Worksheet.Columns.Count - .Column + 1)
    End With
End Function
Sub refBottomRightResizeTEST()
    Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = Range("C5")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = refBottomRightResize(FirstCell)
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then Debug.Print rg.Address
End Sub

Function refNonEmptyRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Range
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set lCell = rg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    With rg.Resize(lCell.Row - rg.Row + 1)
        Set refNonEmptyRange = .Resize(, _
            .Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column - .Column + 1)
    End With
End Function
Sub refNonEmptyRangeTEST()
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Range("C5:F10")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = refNonEmptyRange(irg)
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then Debug.Print rg.Address
End Sub

Function getRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If rg.Rows.Count = 1 And rg.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        getRange = Data
    Else
        getRange = rg.Value
    End If
End Function

Sub writeStringToFile( _
        ByVal FilePath As String, _
        ByVal FileText As String)
    On Error GoTo clearError ' if file path is invalid (folder doesn't exist)
    Dim FileNum As Long: FileNum = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Output As #FileNum
    Print #FileNum, FileText
    Close #FileNum
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
clearError:
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```