# Bad File Mode Error When Writing to Text File

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a logging module for my application.

I'm receiving the following error on the Sub `WriteToLog` when trying to write to the text file:
"Error 54 - Bad File Mode"

**Line**: "fileStream.WriteLine Prefix & Data"

I based that sub off of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49674605/9459575)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Here's my code so far:

```
Private CurrentLogName As String

Public Enum LogLevel
    Info = 0
    Error = 1
End Enum

Public Sub WriteToLog(ByRef Data As String, ByRef LogLevel As Integer)
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim fileStream As TextStream

    On Error GoTo FileError
    Set fileStream = fso.OpenTextFile(CurrentLogName)

    Dim Prefix As String
    Select Case LogLevel
        Case 0
            Prefix = "[Info] "
        Case 1
            Prefix = "[Error] "
        'TODO more cases
    End Select

    fileStream.WriteLine Prefix & Data
    fileStream.Close
    fso = Nothing
    fileStream = Nothing
    GoTo EndSub

    FileError:
        MsgBox "An error occurred while writing to the log file." & vbCrLf & Err.Description, 
        vbCritical, "Error"
    GoTo EndSub
    EndSub:
    End Sub

Private Sub test()
    CreateLogFile
    Call WriteToLog("Test", LogLevel.Error)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in the doc for `.OpenTextFile` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method), there is an optional ioMode parameter that sets the `mode` of the opened file. The doc never specifies, but it appears that default is `ForReading` which naturally will not allow you to (re)write nor append to the file.

Either way, just set the ioMode paramneter specifically to what you need.