# Why is the new file corrupting?

Tags: excel, vba, xlsx

I create a file, and let the user choose at what location.
The file is named with the current date, and the project number.

After that I want to print a cell with Hello world. I dont know if this part works, because I can't open the file. It is corrupt.

```vb
'*************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
'* Folder creater.
'*************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Option Explicit

Sub Acto_Export()
        
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Systems")
  
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
            sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    If sFolder = "" Then  ' if an error occured
        MsgBox ("no folder was selected")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim ProjectNumber As String
    ProjectNumber = Blad1.Cells(8, 4).Value

    Dim ExportFileName As String
    ExportFileName = sFolder & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss_") & ProjectNumber & "_importfileActo.xlsx"

    Open ExportFileName For Output As #1
    Cells(1, 1).Value = "Hello world"

End Sub
```

I think the problem is at the naming of the file. I tried exporting it as a .TXT file and have it just print hello world, but then the file remains empty.

Comment: At what part do you think you're creating a new file? `Open ExportFileName For Output As #1` is something new to me if it would be vba, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11503299/19353309) for creating and writing to a new txt file. If you didn't mean for it to be a new txt file but a new workbook, then just use `Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Add` or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace

```
Open ExportFileName For Output As #1
```

with

```
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ExportFileName
```

The `Open` is used for outputting to text-files and uses typically `Write` or `Print` `"hello world", #1` to output the text to the textfile.

`Cells(1,1).Value="Hello World"` will work with having a new workbook open