# Does the recordset close itself when called from within a function?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

In VBA Programming I am trying to understand the state of a recordset when it is passes data from within a function to another recordset

for example

```
Sub Test()

Dim Recordset1 as new ABODB.Recordset

Set RecordSet1 = BringDataFromRecordset2()

Do while not Recordset1.EOF
'data do something

Recordset1.movenext
Loop
End Sub

Function BringDataFromRecordset2() as ADODB.Recordset
dim RecordSet2 as new ADODB.Recorset

RecordSet2.Open "Select * from DUAL", Connectionstring

BringDataFromRecordset2 = RecordSet2 

End Function
```

What happens to RecordSet2 when it passes the data to RecordSet1 in line "Set RecordSet1 = BringDataFromRecordset2()?

Does it close alutomatically? if RecordSet2 is still open how do I close it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517006/is-there-a-need-to-set-objects-to-nothing-inside-vba-functions

Comment: Thank you for the link. It answers my question

Comment: Why repost the link? Is there a problem?

Comment: I don't know how to close this question... Since you have added the answer as a comment. Please suggest

Comment: I am afraid it means the question should be closed as a duplicate, because it has already been answered.

Comment: Your code as written has a couple of issues.  In the Function you need to use `Set BringDataFromRecordset2 = RecordSet2` since your return value is an object type. In `Test()` you don't need the `New` in the `Recordset1` declaration, since the Function takes care of creating the recordset, and then passes it to Test.  `Recordset2` (or at least the object it points to) is still in scope even after the function completes, because now the `Recordset1` variable in test points to the same object.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams please go ahead and add that as an answer, if you have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as written has a couple of issues. In the Function you need to use

```
Set BringDataFromRecordset2 = RecordSet2
```

since your return value is an object type.

In Test() you don't need the `New` in the Recordset1 declaration, since the Function takes care of creating the recordset, and then passes it to Test.

Recordset2 (or at least the object it points to) is still in scope even after the function `BringDataFromRecordset` completes, because now the Recordset1 variable in `Test` points to the same object.