# classic asp : class in server.executed script is written outside of parent script body

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, iis-10

On IIS 10 (on older IIS servers everything works fine) after some later updates when I work with class in script (*.asp), that was executed (server.execute) from another script then all response.write code written in Class_Terminate() is written to the end of parent body outside the HTML element where it shoud be.

```
<div>
<%server.execute ("somescript.asp")%>
</div>
```

Result from Class_Terminate() in this example is written under the div element. When I include the script instead of executing, everything works fine. The only functional workaroud is to add content of Class_Terminate() to another Sub or Function (like Sub WriteOutput()) in Class and call it at the end of the work with class.. Something like this

```
set Class1=new MyClass
with Class1
...
...
    .WriteOutput
end with
set Class1=nothing
```

Is there any other way? For example to change some setting on the side of IIS? Or is this just a bug, which is going never to be corrected (its classic asp in 2020 I know..) and I have to change the code of all classes?

Comment: Have you got `Response.Buffer =True`?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60089691/893670). The problem you are having is the effect of the same bug on ASP Classic. Still no fix. The workaround is filthy as you can see there.

Comment: Lankymart > yes i do have Response.Buffer = True

Comment: Kul-Tigin > thanks for reply, but easier for me is to replace the class_terminate() with some other function and close objects that way. But of course I have it as a temporary solution.