# How do I write a macro to refresh all data connections for all Excel files in a folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder with many Excel files.  All of them have data connections that connect to a database.  I want to write a macro that refreshes all the data connections for all the files in the folder.  Can anyone point in the right direction to write this macro?  Is this even possible?

Comment: I haven't done this, but I had a former coworker tell me that for this type of work he would loop through and open all files in the folder individually, update the links as part of the loop, then close each once updated.  Not sure how efficient that was, but it was his approach.

Comment: If I had to do this, I would probably 1)[Loop through all the files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793259/loop-through-workbooks-in-the-same-folder-and-do-the-same-excel-task-for-all-vba) 2)[open each one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157385/how-to-open-a-workbook-specifying-its-path) 3) [Run the `.RefreshAll()` method of the currently open workbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-refreshall-method-excel) 4) [save and close the workbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-close-method-excel)

Comment: Does .RefreshAll() refresh the pivot table or the data connection?