# Allow user to specify a directory via the Windows Browse Selection

Tags: vba, excel

Specific to VBA:

Is it possible to ask user to specify a directory name via the standard Windows 'Browse' selection, and read that in as a variable (instead of hard-coding it in the software).

Such as:

```
String MyStr = <Inputted full path by the user via the Windows Browse Selection>
```

Comment: Yes, as per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx) using `Application.FileDialog`

Comment: Thanks. This got me off in the right direction!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30745070/4539709

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function you could use to allow the user to browse for a folder:

```
Public Function pickFolder() As String

    Dim strSelectedItem As String

    Dim dlgPickFolder As FileDialog
    Set dlgPickFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With dlgPickFolder
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
    End With

    If dlgPickFolder.Show = -1 Then
        strSelectedItem = dlgPickFolder.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    Else
    strSelectedItem = ""
    Set fd = Nothing
    End If
    Set fd = Nothing

pickFolder = strSelectedItem

End Function
```

You could use it simply by setting the value of your desired variable using this function:

```
Dim sFolder As String
sFolder = pickFolder()
```

Please let us know if was helpful thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
Set bffShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set bff = bffShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select the My Documents folder", &h4049)
If Err.number<>0 Then
        MsgBox "Error Setting up Browse for Folder"
    Else
        A = bff.ParentFolder.ParseName(bff.Title).Path
        If err.number=424 then err.clear
                Msgbox A
End If
```

I've used following flag options BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS (0x00000001), BIF_RETURNFSANCESTORS (0x00000008), BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE (0x00000040), and BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES (0x00004000).

[image]

These are the flags option from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773205(v=vs.85).aspx

> ulFlags Type: UINT
>
> Flags that specify the options for the dialog box. This member can be
>   0 or a combination of the following values. Version numbers refer to
>   the minimum version of Shell32.dll required for SHBrowseForFolder to
>   recognize flags added in later releases. See Shell and Common Controls
>   Versions for more information.
>
> BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS (0x00000001)
>
> 0x00000001. Only return file system directories. If the user selects
>   folders that are not part of the file system, the OK button is grayed.
>
> Note  The OK button remains enabled for "\server" items, as well as
>   "\server\share" and directory items. However, if the user selects a
>   "\server" item, passing the PIDL returned by SHBrowseForFolder to
>   SHGetPathFromIDList fails.
>
> BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN (0x00000002)
>
> 0x00000002. Do not include network folders below the domain level in
>   the dialog box's tree view control.
>
> BIF_STATUSTEXT (0x00000004)
>
> 0x00000004. Include a status area in the dialog box. The callback
>   function can set the status text by sending messages to the dialog
>   box. This flag is not supported when BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE is specified.
>
> BIF_RETURNFSANCESTORS (0x00000008)
>
> 0x00000008. Only return file system ancestors. An ancestor is a
>   subfolder that is beneath the root folder in the namespace hierarchy.
>   If the user selects an ancestor of the root folder that is not part of
>   the file system, the OK button is grayed.
>
> BIF_EDITBOX (0x00000010)
>
> 0x00000010. Version 4.71. Include an edit control in the browse dialog
>   box that allows the user to type the name of an item.
>
> BIF_VALIDATE (0x00000020)
>
> 0x00000020. Version 4.71. If the user types an invalid name into the
>   edit box, the browse dialog box calls the application's
>   BrowseCallbackProc with the BFFM_VALIDATEFAILED message. This flag is
>   ignored if BIF_EDITBOX is not specified.
>
> BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE (0x00000040)
>
> 0x00000040. Version 5.0. Use the new user interface. Setting this flag
>   provides the user with a larger dialog box that can be resized. The
>   dialog box has several new capabilities, including: drag-and-drop
>   capability within the dialog box, reordering, shortcut menus, new
>   folders, delete, and other shortcut menu commands.
>
> Note  If COM is initialized through CoInitializeEx with the
>   COINIT_MULTITHREADED flag set, SHBrowseForFolder fails if
>   BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE is passed.
>
> BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEURLS (0x00000080)
>
> 0x00000080. Version 5.0. The browse dialog box can display URLs. The
>   BIF_USENEWUI and BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES flags must also be set. If any
>   of these three flags are not set, the browser dialog box rejects URLs.
>   Even when these flags are set, the browse dialog box displays URLs
>   only if the folder that contains the selected item supports URLs. When
>   the folder's IShellFolder::GetAttributesOf method is called to request
>   the selected item's attributes, the folder must set the SFGAO_FOLDER
>   attribute flag. Otherwise, the browse dialog box will not display the
>   URL.
>
> BIF_USENEWUI
>
> Version 5.0. Use the new user interface, including an edit box. This
>   flag is equivalent to BIF_EDITBOX | BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE.
>
> Note  If COM is initialized through CoInitializeEx with the
>   COINIT_MULTITHREADED flag set, SHBrowseForFolder fails if BIF_USENEWUI
>   is passed.
>
> BIF_UAHINT (0x00000100)
>
> 0x00000100. Version 6.0. When combined with BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE, adds a
>   usage hint to the dialog box, in place of the edit box. BIF_EDITBOX
>   overrides this flag.
>
> BIF_NONEWFOLDERBUTTON (0x00000200)
>
> 0x00000200. Version 6.0. Do not include the New Folder button in the
>   browse dialog box.
>
> BIF_NOTRANSLATETARGETS (0x00000400)
>
> 0x00000400. Version 6.0. When the selected item is a shortcut, return
>   the PIDL of the shortcut itself rather than its target.
>
> BIF_BROWSEFORCOMPUTER (0x00001000)
>
> 0x00001000. Only return computers. If the user selects anything other
>   than a computer, the OK button is grayed.
>
> BIF_BROWSEFORPRINTER (0x00002000)
>
> 0x00002000. Only allow the selection of printers. If the user selects
>   anything other than a printer, the OK button is grayed.
>
> In Windows XP and later systems, the best practice is to use a Windows
>   XP-style dialog, setting the root of the dialog to the Printers and
>   Faxes folder (CSIDL_PRINTERS).
>
> BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES (0x00004000)
>
> 0x00004000. Version 4.71. The browse dialog box displays files as well
>   as folders.
>
> BIF_SHAREABLE (0x00008000)
>
> 0x00008000. Version 5.0. The browse dialog box can display sharable
>   resources on remote systems. This is intended for applications that
>   want to expose remote shares on a local system. The BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE
>   flag must also be set.
>
> BIF_BROWSEFILEJUNCTIONS (0x00010000)
>
> 0x00010000. Windows 7 and later. Allow folder junctions such as a
>   library or a compressed file with a .zip file name extension to be
>   browsed.

Answer (score 2):

Code like:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim folder As String
    folder = GetFolder
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful as well and it worked; Thanks!