# VBA queries and cleaning up strings on exit

Tags: vba, ms-access

If I have a query that I have created using VBA:

```
dim SQL as string
dim rs as recordset
dim db as database

SQL = "SELECT ... FROM ..."

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset)
```

At the end of my sub I would always do the following:

```
rs.close
set rs = nothing
```

My question is, do I need to `SQL =""` or something of that like? I think my confusion originally came from the fact that I haven't used `set SQL` in my code.

and if I do clear these strings, then, is there a 'best' way?

Comment: No need to "clear" the strings, they will be destroyed at the end of the procedure.

Comment: In your code `rs` and `db` are objects that can remain in memory, so clearing them at the end is good practice. However 'SQL' is a simple string variable that only exists while the sub is being executed, so this does not need clearing in the same way.

Comment: thanks for the help. I shouldn't have to close db where it is my current db though right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not opening a connection to either CurrentDb or the SQL string, there's no need to close them.  However, you *are* opening a recordset, so that should be closed.  It wouldn't harm anything to set `SQL = ""`, but it's not going to actually do anything constructive.

As far as a "best way", I think you've already got it.  At the end of your sub, or before any code that might prematurely exit it, just put:

```
rs.close
set rs = nothing
```

Comment: To always do `set rs = nothing` is not necessary. Here is an extensive discussion: [Is there a need to set Objects to Nothing inside VBA Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517006/is-there-a-need-to-set-objects-to-nothing-inside-vba-functions), and here an interesting read: [When Are You Required To Set Objects To Nothing?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing.aspx) @LiamH

Comment: @Andre451 - That first link does actually say it's good practice, because Access' garbage collecting is unreliable.  That being said, I recently took over an application that ran just fine for 10 years prior to my involvement, and the previous coder never closed **any** connections.  So, is it necessary?  No.  Is it good practice?  Yes.