# Using With...End when opening recordsets in MsAccess using DAO

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/517202/2669681), the moment a variable goes out of scope then the object's resources will be automatically released by VB.  Question: is it okay if I used `With...End` when opening a DAO.Recordset since the resources is supposed to be cleaned up when the `Sub` goes out of scope, or should I still need to explicitly `Close` and set objects to `Nothing`?

For example,

```
Sub Test()
   With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1", dbOpenForwardOnly)
      IsThisAGoodPractice()
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I still need to explicitly `Close` and set objects to
>   `Nothing`?

Inside the `With` block, you don't have an object variable which references the recordset so there is no way to set it `= Nothing`.  After `End With`, the recordset is gone, so you can't set it `= Nothing` there either --- but it's gone already so that would be pointless.

Regarding its `.Close` method, I would call it same as for any object which includes a `.Close` method.  But whether or not you call it, VBA will still dispose of the recordset at `End With`.

Comment: @HandsUp additional clarifications please, someone told me that it is not good practice to use With...End when opening DAO recordsets and I should still declare the object variables and manually dispose it.  For me, using With..End is much simpler.  Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't see how `With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(...` is all that much simpler than `Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(...`  Is your savings only avoiding `Dim rs As DAO.Recordset`?

Comment: Yes, those variable declarations and manually disposing them.  Or maybe this is just a matter of preference?  Anyway, thanks for you answer!