# copyfile ini to txt: permission-denied

Tags: vba, ms-access, permission-denied, file-copying

I just want to copy the Content of a ini-File into a txt-file. But it tells me, that permission is denied.

- The source file is closed
- the Ini-file "Aly_complete.ini" was previously executed in the code via "java -jar"
- As you see, I already tried another file, which wasn't used by the code before

Here is the code

```
Sub Kopieren_Ini(strPathQuelle As String, strPathErg As String)
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object    
Dim Quelle As String
Dim Ziel As String

If Sheets(1).TxtBoxIni.Text <> "" Then
    Quelle = Sheets(1).TxtBoxIni.Text
Else
    Quelle = strPathQuelle & "Aly_MitDatum.ini"
    'Quelle = strPathQuelle & "Aly_complete.ini"
End If

Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strPathErg & "\" & "Config_Test.txt")
Ziel = strPathErg & "\" & "Config_Test.txt"

FileSystem.FileCopy Quelle, Ziel
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Sounds like the `.ini` is being used by another application or process.  What else is running?  Does this still occur after you reboot?

Comment: Why are you creating a text file, and then copying another file over it? I'd skip that `CreateTextFile` altogether.

Comment: @ashleedawg: It still occures after a restart

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: It is a requirement, that the Input Data from the used ini-file should be saved in the outcome Folder. But it shall not be saved as a ini-file, because it is just for documentation.

Comment: so, you're just trying to copy a file and change it's name, correct?

Comment: yes, but the source file can change by demand

Comment: alright, see my edited [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48948824/8112776).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Sounds like the `.ini` is being used by another application or process.  What else is running?  Does this still occur after you reboot?* <sub>( Source: [*my comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947714/copyfile-ini-to-txt-permission-denied#comment84902806_48947714) ☺)</sub>

Your code is incomplete (it doesn't *End*) so I can't say for sure, but I bet your issue is same common mistake that [imho] is the culprit in almost every complaint of ***Excel crashes*** caused by VBA code...

**It's just like parenta are always telling their children:**

[image: "IF YOU OPEN IT, CLOSE IT!"]

The file is Open (and locked and taking up memory) until you `.Close` it.

**Objects that are opened need to be closed & cleared.**

Try adding these 3 lines to the end of your code (or where ever you're finished using the objects):

```
oFile.Close
Set oFile = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

...then save your work, ***reboot***, and try it again.

---

### More Information:

- Stack Overflow : [Is there a need to set Objects to Nothing inside VBA Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/517006/8112776)
- MSDN : [FileSystemObject Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706(v=vs.60).aspx)
- MSDN : [CreateTextFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/createtextfile-method)
- MSDN : [Close Method (FileSystemObject)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yb3tbdkw(v=vs.84).aspx)

---

## EDIT:  *"Copy & Rename"*

If you simply need to **copy a file** (and **rename** the copy at the same time), use this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyFile()
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fso.copyFile "c:\sourcePath\sourceFile.ini", "c:\destinationPath\destFile.txt"
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

### *More* More Information:

- Rob de Bruin : [Copying & Moving Files with VBA](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win026.htm)
- Excel Trick : [FileSystemObject in VBA – Explained](https://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/filesystemobject-in-vba/)
- MSDN : [CopyFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/copyfile-method)

Comment: oh... and what [@Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947714/copyfile-ini-to-txt-permission-denied/48948824#comment84903350_48947714) said too....

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know, that I have to close oFile, too.

Comment: It's a very common mistake.  ...and if Excel ever crashes on you while running VBA, check for "un-closed" objects first -- I have yet to see or hear of Excel crashing (while running VBA), that isn't somehow related to a ***[memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)*** caused by mishandling objects.

Comment: Oh, and here's an excellent reference on [Copying & Moving Files with VBA](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win026.htm).

Comment: Note that your entire sub can be minimized to one line: `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").copyFile "c:\sourcePath\sourceFile.ini", "c:\destinationPath\destFile.txt"`, without affecting functionality. Since `fso` is never declared, it doesn't need to be destroyed.

Comment: >! ***Shh!**  That's second-week curriculum!*  :)