# Adding new values to the closed excel

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

Tried to add value to closed excel, but I got Run Time Error '91' : Object Variable or With Block not Set.

Code:

```
Dim xl0 As New Excel.Application

  Dim xlw As New Excel.Workbook

  Dim xlsh As Worksheet



  Set xlsh = Sheet3

  Set xlw = xl0.Workbooks.Open("\\Addition\RCA.xlsx")

  xl0.Worksheets.Add

  xl0.xlsh.Cells(1, 1) = RANGECheck

  xl0.xlsh.Cells(1, 2) = RCAInput

  xlw.save

  xlw.Close

  Set xl0 = Nothing

  Set xlw = Nothing
```

Also, the above code enters value in first row, what can we do to add the value after the last row having value?

Comment: `Set xlsh = Sheet3`... that's in this workbook, not the one you open.

Comment: Ohh, so I should write that after `Set xlw = xl0.Workbooks.Open("\\Addition\RCA.xlsx")`

Comment: I'm guessing you're going for `Set xlsh = xlw.Worksheets("Sheet 3")`?

Comment: Yes, and if I go that way I should not use `xl0.Worksheets.Add`

Comment: No need for the last 2 lines in your code where you set your objects to nothing. (`Set xl0 = Nothing`). A reason why from someone much smarter than me can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51065566/what-are-the-benefits-of-setting-objects-to-nothing) :)

Comment: Could you please help me what wrong I did: `Dim ToUser As String



  ToUser = MailSheet.Columns("A:A").Selection.Find(What:=BreaksSheet.Cells(i, colS).Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _

    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _

    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1).Value`, @BigBen

Comment: That seems like a completely new question, but drop that `Selection`... (and you'll also have to test if the `Find` succeeded).

Comment: Ohh, yes got it. Thanks