# How to output specific data and concatenate them into a new column using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my initial excel sheet:
[image: This is my initial excel sheet:]

The output I wish, which is a concatenation of column A and Column B as you can see in column F:
**Note:** I'll add the header "My_Items" manually.
[image: The output I wish, which is a concatenation of column A and Column B:]

Code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lngLastRow As Long

' Selecting all rows
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

'To concatenate both columns and insert the values into a new column
Range("G2").Formula = "=A2 & "": "" & B2"
Range("G2").Copy Range("G3:G" & lngLastRow)
    
End Sub
```

Output after executing the code:
[image: The output after the execution of the code:]
I tried to skip the empty rows using `If Range("A" & ActiveCell.row) <> ""` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think it would be better to output the result as string rather formula. Doing this in a loop (and adding your criteria of `Column A` not being blank) results in a macro something lke:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update
Dim lr As Long, i As Long

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 2 To lr
    If ws.Range("A" & i) <> "" Then
        ws.Range("F" & i) = ws.Range("A" & i) & ": " & ws.Range("B" & i)
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

If you do want to stick with the formula output you need to update the formula to consider the blank cells. Consider how you would do this in the excel sheet (*`=IF(A1<>"",A1&": "&B1,""`*). I.E. you formula is missing the conditional `IF`

Answer (score 1):

This code will cycle through the cells in column A that have something in them and concatenate the value of column A and column B into Column G

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim xlCellA As Range
    Dim LstR As Long
        Set xlCellA = Range("A2")
        LstR = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        Do Until xlCellA.Row > LstR
            If xlCellA.Value = "" Then
                xlCellA.Offset(0, 6).Value = xlCellA.Value & ": " & xlCellA.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If
            Set xlCellA = xlCellA.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop
        Set xlCellA = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: No need to `Set xlCellA = Nothing` at end. The objects references will die with the macro

Comment: Unfortunately, this method didn't produce my desired output. But I can see that this method would prove to be useful to me soon. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @urdearboy true, however it is good coding practice to make sure that your references are killed when no longer needed

Comment: @GlennG - I hear you but I believe this is where VBA deviates from others. Not all best practices apply everywhere. The solution in [my past question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51066727/6706419) is worth a read :)