# Performance leak at runtime with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I created an Excel sheet with a VBA macro. The data written is read from a binary file. From this binary file, I consider every x byte represents a frame. A frame is written on a row, with a header.

**First issue :**
As I write those data, there is a noticeable performance leak over time : the first 250 frames are done under a minute, then the next 150 take one minute. Overall, at the beginning of the process, ~10 frames are done in 1 second. After a few hundreds of frames, it takes more than a second to process 1 frame. Time is measured by hand, according to a progress bar.

**Second issue :**
I have a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event on the sheet that calls `Cells(row, 1).EntireRow.Hidden` setting it to `True` or `False` depending on the situation. After some debugger inspection, I have realized those instructions take an increasing amount of time depending on the amount of data written during the session. Example, it takes a good 10 seconds with ~400 frames.

**Now the part that makes me think there is room for improvement :** 
If I save the file, close it, reopen it, and change the selection, `Cells(row, 1).EntireRow.Hidden` takes an insignificant amount of time. I'd even say, the expected amount of time.
If I only save the file and keep it open, there is no noticeable change.

**What's I've tried :**
In order to improve performances, at the beginning of the main sub, I call :

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlcalculationmanual
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
```

(and swap them back to their original values at the end)

I already avoid as much as possible the use of `Select` and `Activate`.
I also avoid arrays, using Collections instead, since I've read its faster.
I use the `With` statement whenever necessary.
I make sure the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` is disabled before writing into the file.

I believe both issues are related, but I do not understand what is the cause or how I can solve it. What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT:**
Using `Application.SaveWorkspace` every 100 frames does the job : it pauses the process (visibly thanks to the progress bar) for ~2 seconds but the amount of time saved to process the next 100 frames is entirely compensated.
I think that my problem is solved now, unless there is a cleaner way to do that. Thanks a lot to all of you in comments !

**EDIT 2 :**
Problem solved : I was adding comments to some cells, using `selectedCell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True` every time like so :

```
    With sheet.Cells(row, column)
        .AddComment txt
        .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    End With
```

The goal being to make them look pretty. For some reasons, this is what was slowing down the whole process each time it was called.

Instead, I now call the following snippet at the very end.
For the information, 100 frames are now processed in under 10s, and the process time is constant. For ~400 frames, the following snippet took 16s (approx).

```
    Dim comment As Comment
    For Each comment In sheet.Comments
        comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    Next comment
```

Comment: First issue: does the performance improve if you comment out writing to Excel cells? Does the performance improve if you remove the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` function? Are there are event handlers?

Comment: @ŁukaszNojek I've just tried, the performance is significantly better and most importantly linear without writing to the Excel cells. There is no performance change when the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event is empty of code. I didn't get your question about event handlers, can you develop on it ?

Comment: I understand that you checked both cases separately - not writing to Excel with the SelectionChanged sub, and writing to Excel without the SelectionChanged sub? By event handlers I meant functions similar to `Worksheet_SelectionChange`. Are there any other?

Comment: The only other event on the sheet is `Worksheet_Activate`, that I've also emptied during the test. I've tested both cases separately and together, to be sure they didn't impact each other. Result went accordingly to what was described.

Comment: Do you do any formatting to the rows/cells? Can you show the code that writes a row? I try to do as many bulk operations as possible, so e.g. I don't set format on a cell in 3rd column immediately when creating a new row, but I set format for the entire 3rd column or range "C2:C700" at once after I finished writing.

Comment: I actually do, yeah. I'll move all the formatting to the step following all the writing, and edit this comment with the perf. result.

Comment: The performance while writing is indeed better, but the slow down takes effect on all the formatting now, being overall slower :(

Comment: I could see if I can help if you shared some example that is slow. I have no further generic ideas ;).

Comment: I'll see what I can do about that :)

Comment: Would you accept moving it to chat ? It would be more fitting to our conversation, i think

Comment: I would post all code there may be room for improvement - I believe that arrays are faster than collections, where did you read otherwise? - great observation re the slowdown over time - maybe has to do with memory allocation?

Comment: All code represents over 2000 actual lines of code, not including comments and blanks. Plus its company work, i can't just publish that online. I'm trying to isolate parts of the code that may be related. It does look like its related to memory allocation, since closing & reopening the file does the job, but i can't find in what way.

Comment: still learning but you may want to take care to set objects = nothing see the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38850956/9721351

Comment: I'll watch that closely, thanks @learnAsWeGo, you taught me something!

Comment: Consider reading your data into an array, and then inserting that in one hit into the Excel sheet. Then hide the relevant rows in one command/function (what that looks like will depend on how you choose rows to hide). This approach should significantly improve performance. Of course, without any code and sample (sanitised/anonymised) data can't provide specific hints.

Comment: @AJD It is indeed a lot faster just sending an array to a range, it helped a lot. @learnAsWeGo setting objets to Nothing does help, but it is not very noticeable because i use a lot of primitives. Right now I use a `Application.SaveWorkspace` every 100 frames and it does the job. Despite pausing for a second, the amount of time saved afterward is a very good compensation. (question updated to add this)

Comment: For whoever follows this thread, problem is solved, explanations in EDIT2 of the question. Thanks !

Comment: @ape I wonder why application.saveworkspace would speed up?

Comment: I'm not sure, it also created an additional file (extension was .xl something) that referred to the Excel file. To be honest, the speedup was seen once, may be a fluke. I should delete that from the main post, maybe

Comment: @ape maybe it moves memory out of RAM into hardrive or ssd?