# Simple Select All Text & Save to File Using Selenium & VBA

Tags: vba, selenium

I'm new to selenium, & not familiar with its syntax.

I'm trying to figure out how to send Control A & save all the selected text to a file.

If someone could post some examples of sending Control A & saving all the selected text to a basic text file, it'd save me huge amounts of time.

I've managed to get selenium working, but cant figure out the syntax as its different from Vba ...

Thanks.,

```
Public Sub scrapeCIL()
Dim bot As New WebDriver, posts As WebElements, post As WebElement, i As Integer, mysheet As Worksheet, keys As Selenium.keys
bot.Start "chrome", "https://www.binance.com/en/trade/BTC_USDT"
bot.Get "/"


bot.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do `CTRL + A` using the below code :

```
wd.findElementByTagName("body").click
wd.SendKeys Keys.Control, "a"
```

and create your text file and write it like this :

```
Option Explicit

' Go to Tools -> References... and check "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" to be able to use
' the FileSystemObject which has many useful features for handling files and folders
Public Sub SaveTextToFile()

    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = "C:\temp\MyTestFile.txt"

    ' The advantage of correctly typing fso as FileSystemObject is to make autocompletion
    ' (Intellisense) work, which helps you avoid typos and lets you discover other useful
    ' methods of the FileSystemObject
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim fileStream As TextStream

    ' Here the actual file is created and opened for write access
    Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath)

    ' Write something to the file
    fileStream.WriteLine "something"

    ' Close it, so it is not locked anymore
    fileStream.Close

    ' Here is another great method of the FileSystemObject that checks if a file exists
    If fso.FileExists(filePath) Then
        MsgBox "Yay! The file was created! :D"
    End If

    ' Explicitly setting objects to Nothing should not be necessary in most cases, but if
    ' you're writing macros for Microsoft Access, you may want to uncomment the following
    ' two lines (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/517202/2822719 for details):
    'Set fileStream = Nothing
    'Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Reference taken from [How to create and write to a txt file using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503174/how-to-create-and-write-to-a-txt-file-using-vba)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply

I shouldve said save the selected text using control a, in selenium directly from the browser, not vba

I know how to use vba to save files, but i dont know how to save text using selenium directly from the browser

Thanks!

Comment: @GenusMax : The copied text is in universal clipboard, Can you read from from a clipboard ?

Comment: Hi I tried bot.findElementByTagName("body").Click
bot.SendKeys keys.Control, "a"

But it gives Object does not support this method or property error. I just need to save all the text from https://www.binance.com/en/trade/BTC_USDT every 1 second & save it to a file. Doesnt have to use Ctrl A. The text has to be saved to a variable, not clipboard. I cant use the clipboard as i use the clipboard in another script. Thanks!